# Scrollbar showing and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am somewhat between new and intermediate at web designing / coding...
Here goes!
if you look at this :

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPufX/

the css indicates an auto scrollbar on the y axis.
the thing is that i am having problems making it to show up only when the text (multiple "some text" in the code) shows up, and morover, it is not even scrolling as it is...

any clue?

---

found the answer!!

in the  propreties on the css file, go something like this :

```
div.example
{width: 960px;
height: 430px;
position: relative;
top: 90px;
left: 296px;
overflow: hidden;}
```

and then :

```
div.example
{width: 960px;
height: 430px;
position: relative;
top: 90px;
left: 296px;
overflow: scroll;}
```

this will cause the scrollbar to appear only when hovering over the  box !

thanks to vimalnath for his help on the subject!

Comment: #textbox, #textbox2 {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 450px;
    left: 296px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;//changed from absolute
    top: 90px;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 10;
}

Comment: thanks!! this solves the not working toolbar problem!! =) now how do i make it to appear only when the text (and/or the div textbox) appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to change the position of the textbox to relative from absolute

Demo here:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPufX/6/)

Comment: thanks!! this solves the not working toolbar problem!! =) now how do i make it to appear only when the text (and/or the div textbox) appears?

Comment: I have updated my answer.
You could use jquery to check if the textbox is empty.

Comment: Wooosh! close!! the thing is that the textbox is not empty : the text is here but the opacity is set to 0 (moving up to 1 with the jQuery [""$("#text").delay(500).animate({opacity:1},200);""] line). So is there another option for that?!  or maybe i inserted your jQuery lines unproperly in my html..

Comment: I have made jquery to work in a way that if the content inside textbox is empty then scrollbar is hidden else make it visible

var content = $('#textbox').html();
if(content) {
    $('#textbox').css("overflow","scroll");
    $('#textbox2').css("overflow","scroll");
} else{
    $('#textbox').css("overflow","hidden");
    $('#textbox2').css("overflow","hidden");
}

Comment: =$ still not working.. i inserted <script style="text/javascript">"your script"</script> in the <head> section of my .html... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you included jquery.js file in your script?
Also, share your fiddle